# Error on Adding ActionBarSherlock in Intellij-Idea 13

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

After adding the library in project by all tutorial I have an error in style.xml

```
Error: No resources found that matches the given name: attr 'switchStyle'
Error: No resources found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearance'
```

In Eclipse i can choose "clean project" and this problem disappear until next change in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_light</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

My steps:

- Project created in Eclipse and now imported to IntelliJ IDEA
- Project and ActionBar SDK settings - Google Android 4.4.2
- Manifest project settings: minSDK - 10; target SDK - 19
- Add module to project setting (not jar - all ActionBar project by import module -> chose ActionBar folder -> create module from existing source or import from external module Eclipse)
- Add in module dependency to support-v4
- Add ActionBar module to dependency for Project module
- In Facets ActionBar module is library
- Remove from imported ActionBar module test folder
- Rebuild project - error
- Make project - error.

PS. Project is old, created in Eclipse without Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was in dependencies of third part module from ActionBarSherlock. All trace was:
- My project have dependency from ActionBarSherlock and other module which also have dependency from ABS
- Project refers to style of ActionBar **BUT** in this third part module

The whole thing turned out to be in my inattention

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to replace module dependency with AAR. Just add this to your  `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

2) Check your theming. You need to create a custom style for ActionBar, and then apply it. Here is a sample of proper way to do it:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It's old project created in Eclipse without Gradle. Now i'm trying to import project in Intellij. But other members of team still work in Eclipse.

Comment: @DreamVan why do you not use Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio is same Intellij, isn't it? Team don't want to change IDE from Eclipse

Comment: Yeap, basically it's Intellij. But Android Studio uses `gradle` as a build tool, what is a huge step forward